# Google Sheets + Apps Script + Webapps: update existing row that matches the ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I got this script and webapp that pull the row that matches the id number from my webapp now what I'm trying to do is update the row that matches the ID in my google sheet column 'A' I don't want to create a new row I just want it to replace / update the existing row that matches the ID number from my webapp once I've made change and click on the update button

link to the google sheet page
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eaEfRtjMz7kyQfyXZHLuBhSz91SiUJzq1J2QJexJxy4/edit?ts=5fc42833#gid=0

Thanks

**gs code**

```
    function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
 
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
/* @Process Form */




function editCustomerById(Id,custDetail){
 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const custIds = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues().map(r => r[0].toString().toLowerCase());
  const posIndex = custIds.indexOf(Id.toString().toLowerCase());
  const rowNumber = posIndex === -1 ? 0 : posIndex + 2;
  
  
  ws.getRange(rowNumber, 2,1,8).setValues([[              
  
                custDetail.Date,
                custDetail.client,
                custDetail.location,
                custDetail.other1, 
                custDetail.other2,
                                  
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         ]]);
  return true;
}


function getCustDetail(search) {
  search = Number(search);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var idvCustData = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
  var custIdList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var custDateList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });
  var custclientList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[3]; });
  var custlocationList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[4]; });
  var custother1List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[5]; });
  var custother2List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[6]; });
  var searchPostion = custIdList.indexOf(search);
  var custDetail = {};
  custDetail.Id = custIdList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.Date = custDateList[searchPostion] && Utilities.formatDate(custDateList[searchPostion], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  custDetail.client = custclientList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.location = custlocationList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.other1 = custother1List[searchPostion];
  custDetail.other2 = custother2List[searchPostion];
  if (searchPostion > -1){
    return  custDetail;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**JS code**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
     
      
      });
    }
  
  document.getElementById("Id").addEventListener("change",getCustomer);
  
  
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);  
  
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    
  






}           
               
               

//Retrieve Customer
function getCustomer() {
  
  var searchId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
  
 if (searchId!= ""){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(custDetail).getCustDetail(searchId);
  } 
  
}

//Success Handler
function custDetail(cust){
  if (cust) {
    document.getElementById("Id").value = cust.Id;
    document.getElementById("Date").value = cust.Date;
    document.getElementById("client").value = cust.client;
    document.getElementById("location").value = cust.location;
    document.getElementById("other1").value = cust.other1;
    document.getElementById("other2").value = cust.other2;
    M.updateTextFields();
  }
}





 function editCustomer(){
          
          var custDetail = {};
          
   
         
         custDetail.Date = document.getElementById("Date").value
         custDetail.client = document.getElementById("client").value
         custDetail.location = document.getElementById("location").value
         custDetail.other1 = document.getElementById("other1").value
         custDetail.other2 = document.getElementById("other2").value
         
         
          
          
          var id = document.getElementById("Id").value;
          
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().editCustomerById(id,custDetail);
      
      }
      
</script>
```

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    <?!= include('CSS'); ?>
    
    <!-- Select2 CDN -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        
        
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
   
   
   
   
     <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity= "sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, jquery and jQuery autocomplete -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script> 
    <script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script> 
    <script src= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>   

    </head>
   
      <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                      <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Ticket Form</p>
                      
                      
           <div class="form-row">
           
           
           
           

              
               <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="Id">ID</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id" name ="Id">
              </div>
              
             
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="Date">Ticket Date</label>
               <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Date" name ="Date">
              </div>
              
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="client">Client</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" >
               </div>
                           
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="location">Location</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" >
               </div>
             </div>
   
          <div class="form-row">
             
             <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="other1">Other1</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other1" name ="other1">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="other2">Other2</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other2" name="other2" >
               </div>
                
            </div>
               <hr>
                 <br>
                         
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-md-4 ">Update</button>
                        
             </form>

                     <br>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                  </div>
                 </div>      
                </div>
               </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: In your question, when an ID which is not included in the Spreadsheet is put, what do you want to do?

Comment: if the ID is non existing I want it to do nothing just cancel the prosses

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script in your question, I thought that the function of `processForm` might be required to be modified. But it seems that the function of `processForm` is not included. Can you provide it?

Comment: I've tried adding a piece of code from an other post that you reply to that  used the processForm but I was unable to successfully use it so I went back to try it with this code that is on my google sheet now but i still cant get it to update the row containing the ID

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had wanted to confirm your current script of `processForm`. From your replying, you have no script of `processForm` for confirming your current situation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: that is correct I have no processForm script please don't apologize for your English skill your English skill are very good .

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I suggested a sample script of `processForm` for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When "Update" button is clicked, you want to check the ID from the Spreadsheet.
- When the ID is existing in the column "A" of Spreadsheet, you want to update the same row.
- When the ID is not existing in the column "A" of Spreadsheet, you are not required to process.

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your case, the script of `processForm` is required to be modified. But from your replying, I understood that you have no script of `processForm`.
- When `google.script.run.processForm(formObject)` in your Javascript is run, at Google Apps Script side, `formObject` is parsed like `{"Id":"##","other2":"##","location":"##","client":"##","Date":"##","other1":"##"}`. I think that using this value, the ID of column "A" can be searched using TextFinder.

#### Modified script:

Please add the following script of `processForm` to the Google Apps Script side.

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  var range =  sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(formObject.Id).findNext();
  if (range) {
    var values = [[new Date(),formObject.Date,formObject.client,formObject.location,formObject.other1,formObject.other2]];
    range.offset(0, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, it supposes that the same IDs are not included in the column "A". Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: I don't know what im doing wrong I've added your code to my gs code but when i click update button it clear but no update on the google sheet any suggestion

Comment: got it it was the var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data') I've put var ws = sheet.getSheetByName('Data')

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I'm worry that your script might be different from my understanding script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.